# Why css class exist i never made in anywhere

Tags: javascript

Thank you for what you see my sentence.
I am going to use if() for something. but it did not work.
And i tried to figure out what`s problem.

When i write code in javascript files like this

```
console.log(!!($('.something')));
```

chrome said me true like this:[image]

Please tell me what i didn`t know...
Thank you.

Comment: Please clearly tell us what `it did not work` means.

Comment: $('.something') returns an object, and objects are truthy

Comment: sorry for my obscure explain..

Answer (score 1):

`$('.something')` will always return a jquery object, even when no elements for the selector exist.

To check if the selector matches any elements try `$('.something').length > 0` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding how horrible my question!
Through your comment, I resolve my problem!
Thanks a a lot:)